# Как правильно регистрировать vue компоненты в Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

В Laravel, не знаю с какой версии предлагается, подключать компоненты таким образом
[image: Код подключения]

Раньше я подключал необходимые мне вложенные компоненты из других, как правильно пользоваться этим импортом? Это ведь по сути должно значительно увеличить время загрузки страницы

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего для большого приложения использовать vue cli + laravel, инструкция для подключения вот тут: https://github.com/starkovsky/laravel-vue-cli